# What punctuation should you use after a list?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons, dashes

What punctuation should you use after a list and before describing the list? In the example below, what should I use where I have used a dash? Or is the dash correct?

"Some examples of Apple’s innovative technologies include the retina display, touch ID, and Apple pay - features that provide convenience and security to users."

Answer (score 1):

From the Oxford Dictionaries [Punctuation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/punctuation) guide.

The [hyphen](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/hyphen) you used is often seen but strictly has a different use. It is more correct to use the [Em dash](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/dash-and-em-dash).

> Some examples of Apple’s innovative technologies include the retina display, touch ID, and Apple pay — features that provide convenience and security to users.

Also their [Colon](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/colon) guide supports *its* use in your sentence

> Some examples of Apple’s innovative technologies include the retina display, touch ID, and Apple pay: features that provide convenience and security to users.

Comment: Yep, and has little to do with being preceded by a list vs a single clause.